# unknown module "child_process" in react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

`React Native v0.23.0`

`Node v5.11.0`

<del>`Windows 10 10586`</del> (I try on OSX and get the same error)

I try to write `var cp = require('child_process');` in react native, but get an error said `Requiring unknown module "child_process"`. How to fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got answer at this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7170

Answer (score 0):

There is a react-native-childprocess package you could try