# How can I invoke a command line program from React Native on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I read [unknown module “child_process” in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808305/unknown-module-child-process-in-react-native).
I think that technically it is possible to invoke a command line program via [Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android).
Are there any native modules available like child_process?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think this is possible, Android & IOS comes with its own security policies and due to security reasons, this should not be possible. You must read how an app spawns its own process and has no access to create new child_process or modify other processes.

Comment: Is it impossible even if the app includes the command line program?

Comment: Yes. it won't allow. you can check termux app which gives terminal access to android device. might get an idea.

Comment: I am confused. termux app does it, so it is possible, isn’t it?

Comment: Great! if it allows. I was not aware, then it should be possible. Sorry for the wrong information. But as per my understanding, any device will create a new process associated with process_id for any single application open, and creating a new one was not possible basically, I tried running a node.js code in the terminal and I was getting some error a long time back.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information! I keep investigating the way.

Comment: Now I gradually understand what balaji san said. "Removed execute permission for app home directory" in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10. I am not sure but still you may invoke a command line program in your APK.